# Some .dll files are missing in WIN8.1 OS?

Tags: dll

I'm trying to register a dll file(32bit) in windows 8.1 os,
but somehow I check the dll from Dependency Walker and find out 
Some .dll files are missing in WIN8.1 OS as follow:

```
   1. API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
   2. API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
   3. API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
   4. API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
   5. EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
   6. IESHIMS.DLL
```

I google it and the problem is about upgrade OS to WIN8.1,
but how can I make these .dll files back?
or is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Ditto, there is an MSDN forum that other folks are reporting this as well and it doesn't look like Microsoft says there is an issue.  One solution is to go back to Windows 8.0.   http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/32-bit-application-fails-to-start-after-81-upgrade/b825723e-e2a2-4c8f-bd1f-10446a5d7059

Comment: Same problem here... posted another question about it since this one is unanswered.

Comment: This is my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604222/missing-dlls-in-opengl-windows-8-1). 
I'm allowed to do things like this right?

Comment: I had this problem, but it turned out to be a false positive given by the dependecy walker. You should check whether you are missing another dll.

Comment: Did you install the right version of vcredist?

Comment: @gumlym is right. I checked my Evernote.exe with depends22.  Evernote.exe misses all the dll you mentioned, but it runs very well.